# Subtracting two tables in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel-4, eloquent

Hi I was able to get the values from two tables, now I want this two values to be subtracted. How can i do it here in laravel?

```
public function displayBalance()
    {
        $results= DB::table('accountspayable')
            ->selectRaw('sum(accountspayable.amount) as sum')
            ->where('accountspayable.regnum','=','15459')
            ->get();

        $subjects= DB::table('pay')
            ->selectRaw('sum(pay.amount) as sum')
            ->join('accountspayable','pay.accountno','=','accountspayable.accountno')
            ->where('accountspayable.regnum','=','15459')
            ->get();

    return View::make('users.Balance')->with(array('results'=>$results,'subjects'=>$subjects));
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do: `$results - $subjects` ?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I did but its not a supported operand

Comment: What is the datatype you get for `$results` and `$subjects`?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek integers

Comment: How is `-` not a support operand for integers? So after you declared those to variables (which turn out as integers), doing something like: `$someVar = $results - $subjects` does not work? It may be a string like `"10"` and not a number. Try casting them: `$someVar = (int)$results - (int)$subjects`

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I tried this `$answers= DB::raw('($results - $subjects) as balance');` I did not receive any errors however I was not able to retrieve any data :O

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I just checked my datatype and its numeric, but its not any diff with integers right?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
public function displayBalance()
{
    $results = DB::table('accountspayable')->
        where('regnum'. '='. '15459')->
        sum('amount');

    $subjects = DB::table('pay')->
        join('accountspayable','pay.accountno','=','accountspayable.accountno')->
        where('accountspayable.regnum','=','15459')->
        sum('pay.amount');

    return View::make('users.Balance', compact('results', 'subjects'));
}
```

You were probably getting collections of 1 record having 1 attribute (sum). And that's the only thing you basically need. So you can use aggregate functions directly in your query builder to get the SUM values.

Also I used "compact" to assign the values you just retrieved to the view. This is not necessary but  saves some code and is easier to read.